# Use events for struts2 form submission

Tags: struts2-jquery

How can we use  events (on change,on click etc..) on a struts2 field as submitting a form or to call an action support class? i'm using struts2 with jquery and ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply submit the form on clicking of a button as below :

```
<form name="myform">
    <!-- Other form elements -->
</form>


<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="document.forms['myform'].submit();"/>
```